# ipywidgets: positioning output widgets from different VBoxes so that they're in line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks, ipywidgets

Background: I'm using ipywidgets within Databricks notebook, and am new to ipywidgets and to HTML/CSS.

I'm trying to display output in ipywidgets in a question and answer format, that will allow successive questions and answers to be displayed. However, when a given question or answer spills over into a second line, it messes up the output that follows as can be seen in attached image.

How do I set up the output widgets so that the labels for the questions and answers on the left hand side will always line up with the questions and answers themselves on the right?

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRvJ8.png)

I have set up the widgets to be 4 output widgets, the two for labels held in a VBox on the left, and the two for the question and answer held in a VBox on the right. The two VBoxes are in turn held within a HBox. Each time there is a question/answer pair, 4 new output widgets will be created and added to the VBoxes.

I don't know how update the below code to ensure that the associated label on the left and output on the right will always be in line. I tried other box options such as GridspecLayout and TwoByTwoLayout but these didn't seem to work very well with the output widgets.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

question_label = "Question:"
answer_label = "Answer:"

question_list = ["What is 2+2?", "What is the full text of Loren ipsum?", "What is 3+3?"]
answer_list = ["4", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "6"]

vbox_output_left = widgets.VBox([], layout = widgets.Layout(min_width = '10%'))
vbox_output_right = widgets.VBox([])

hbox_output = widgets.HBox([vbox_output_left, vbox_output_right]) #, layout = widgets.Layout(margin = '10px 20px 10px 20px'))
display(hbox_output)


for i in range(0, len(question_list)):
    question = question_list[i]
    answer = answer_list[i]

    output_top_left = widgets.Output()
    output_bottom_left = widgets.Output()
    output_top_right = widgets.Output()
    output_bottom_right = widgets.Output()

    vbox_output_left.children = vbox_output_left.children + (output_top_left, output_bottom_left)
    vbox_output_right.children = vbox_output_right.children + (output_top_right, output_bottom_right)

    with output_top_left:
        print(question_label)
    with output_bottom_left:
        print(answer_label)

    with output_top_right:
        print(question)
    with output_bottom_right:
        print(answer)
```